# iPad background-attachment: fixed issue

Tags: html, css

I was trying to use fixed auto scaling background image for a website design I'm working on. Everything works fine here...

http://cssdeck.com/labs/3e2as8xw

...however, the scaling and fixed background combination does not work on iPad. For some reason, when the fixed background-attachment is activated in css, the background image tries to scale according to the whole size of the body (the whole text, not the screenArea/body). Therefore, the image becomes useless and too big if the site content is too long.

As far as I can google, it looks like background-attachment is not suported for iPad. I'm looking for alternative solutions in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. adding meta doesnt work.. is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ios meta tags.

This will prevent scaling:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320, initial-scale = 2.3, user-scalable = no">
```